# Building Caffe on Ubuntu: make can't find Boost's include files

Tags: ubuntu, boost, include, caffe

I am following [these instructions](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) to install and build Caffe along with its dependencies. I built Boost and got this at the end:

```
The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:
   /home/ubuntu/Caffe/boost_1_57_0
The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
   /home/ubuntu/Caffe/boost_1_57_0/stage/lib
```

When I run `make all` in the caffe directory, I get this:

```
CXX src/caffe/blob.cpp
In file included from ./include/caffe/blob.hpp:8:0,
             from src/caffe/blob.cpp:4:
./include/caffe/common.hpp:4:32: fatal error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/blob.o] Error 1
```

What do I need to modify for it to find the include (and lib) files? A specific environment variable? A setting in caffe's Makefile? Something else?

Answer (score 12):

Probably you do not have `boost` installed on your machine

```
 sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends libboost-all-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
cd /usr/include/boost/thread
sudo ln -s locks.hpp latch.hpp
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copy your boost folder that you have built (must be named as "boost") to your `/usr/local/include` or `/usr/include`. Then run `make all` again.